# Create UITableView Using Swift Program

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a UITableView using code, I am not using any storyboard or IB.

Following is my code:

```
class UserListController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var chatTableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return table
    }()
func setChatTableView(){
        chatTableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        chatTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: chatSegmentControl.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        chatTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        chatTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }



override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(chatTableView)
        setChatTableView()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    let cellIdentifier = "cellId"




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath
//        ) as UITableViewCell

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "LaLaLa"
        return cell
    }
```

I have created chatTableView which is my TableView and have add this on the main view i am not using UITableViewController.

I can see the table view on screen but there is no message in rows so what I should do to populate table view please help.
I am new to the ios and using a swift 4.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's missing : `table.delegate = self`, `table.datasource = self`, maybe `table.reloadData()` too.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`

```
var chatTableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView()
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self
    table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return table
}()
```

You can also get full tutorial over [Here](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/create-uitableview-programmatically-example-in-swift/).

Comment: i had to use "lazy var chatTableView" for using self inside closure